# Simplifying expression (answer given)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplifying expression:

$$\frac{3}{4}(b-a)\left( \frac{ 2a}{3} + \frac{b}{3} \right) + \left( \frac{b-a}{4}\right) b$$

How do I simplify this to get $\frac{b^2-a^2}{2}?$ Do I need to multiply everything by $4$ to start?

Comment: You don't have an equation so you can't multiply by anything not $1$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{3}{4}(b-a)\left( \frac{2a}{3} + \frac{b}{3} \right) + \left( \frac{b-a}{4}\right) b$$
Now, just multiply each term
$$=\dfrac{(3b-3a)(2a+b)}{12}+\dfrac{b^2-ab}4$$
$$=\dfrac{6ab+3b^2-6a^2-3ab}{12}+\dfrac{\color{red}3(b^2-ab)}{\color{red}3\cdot4}$$
$$=\dfrac{3ab+3b^2-6a^2+3b^2-3ab}{12}$$
$$=\dfrac{6b^2-6a^2}{12}$$
$$=\dfrac{b^2-a^2}{2}$$

Answer (score 3):

You factor out $\dfrac{b-a}4$ and expand what remains, giving

$$\frac{3\cdot2}3+\frac{3b}3+b=2(a+b).$$

Then the product is

$$\frac{(b-a)(b+a)}{2}=\frac{b^2-a^2}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\frac{3}{4}(b-a)\left( \frac{2a}{3} + \frac{b}{3} \right) + \left( \frac{b-a}{4}\right) b$$

$$\frac{\color{red}3}{4}\frac1{\color{red}3}(b-a)\left( 2a+b\right) + \left( \frac{b-a}{4}\right) b$$

$$\frac14\left[(b-a)\left( 2a+b\right) + \left( b-a\right) b\right]$$

$$\frac14\left(\color{red}{2ab}+b^2-2a^2\color{red}{-ab}+b^2\color{red}{-ab}\right)=\frac{b^2-a^2}{2}$$

Comment: Please don't post simple answers (incomplete) so you can then edit them.

Comment: @amWhy That was complete from the first editing, I'm only improving with some minor adjustment by colors for the presentation. Moreover it is a completely different approach with respect to teh answer by Key Flex.

Comment: @amWhyI really don't understand what you are referring to! Do not exaggerate please, you are going beyond what I'm prone to allow.